# Tab button with outer round corner

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, skinning

I want to create a skin for TabBarButton looking like that sample: [image]

There are out-rounded bottom corners. How I can make this with MXML marking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button skin for the `Rect` set positive y radius and negative x radius.

```
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
            bottomLeftRadiusX="-5" bottomLeftRadiusY="5"
            bottomRightRadiusX="-5" bottomRightRadiusY="5">
```